# lzma compress/Uncompress from memory c++

Tags: c++, 7zip, lzma

I have a code working, but i'm not entirely satisfied of the result, so I figured I could  ask some questions here.

Here are my two functions :

```
void compress(string nameSrc, string nameDst){

    ifstream input;
    input.open(nameSrc,fstream::in | fstream::binary);

    size_t propsSize = LZMA_PROPS_SIZE;
    size_t srcLen = getLength(input);
    size_t dstLen = srcLen; //??? no idea how to know to right value here

    unsigned char* src = new unsigned char[srcLen];
    unsigned char* dst = new unsigned char[dstLen + propsSize];

    input.read((char*)src, srcLen);

    int res = LzmaCompress(
        &dst[LZMA_PROPS_SIZE], &dstLen,
        src, srcLen,
        dst, &propsSize,
        -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);

    delete [] src;
    input.close();

    ofstream output(nameDst, ios::binary);
    output.write((char*)dst, dstLen + propsSize);

    delete [] dst;


}
```

and :

```
void unCompress(string nameSrc, string nameDst){

    ifstream input;
    input.open(nameSrc,fstream::in | fstream::binary);

    size_t srcLen = getLength(input);
    size_t dstLen = srcLen*5; //??? no idea how to know to right value here

    unsigned char* src = new unsigned char[srcLen];
    unsigned char* dst = new unsigned char[dstLen];

    input.read((char*)src,srcLen);

    int res = LzmaUncompress(dst,&dstLen,&src[LZMA_PROPS_SIZE],&srcLen, src, LZMA_PROPS_SIZE);

    delete [] src;
    input.close();

    ofstream output(nameDst, ios::binary);
    output.write((char*)dst, dstLen);

    delete [] dst;
}
```

---

1. In both function, how am I supposed to know what value to put into dstLen ? I don't want to allocate a lot of memory for nothing.
2. Is it bad that I have to cast to char* ? Do I really have to use unsigned char ?
3. I tried changing the last argument of LzmaCompress (numThreads), it didn't improve the performance, not even slightly. Is there something else to do ?
4. if you have any tips, feel free to tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what are these `Lzma*ompress()` functions, where do they come from? Is there any documentation about them? While I can imagine the post-processed sizes can be unknown (especially for compression), compressed data likely includes the original size that should be easily extractable. Documentation and the explanation of the compression algorithm should also give you an idea about the `numThreads` parameter, whether it's going to be helpful or not (some compression/decompression algorithms are inherently sequential and cannot be parallelized).

Comment: they come from the LZMA SDK (http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html). Yes, once the data are compressed, I can know the size. My problem is that I have to allocate the memory before that.

Answer (score 1):

Use following function to get destination size:

```
INT32
EFIAPI
LzmaGetInfo(
CONST VOID  *Source,
UINT32      SourceSize,
UINT32      *DestinationSize
)
{
    UInt64  DecodedSize;

    ASSERT(SourceSize >= LZMA_HEADER_SIZE); (void)SourceSize;

    DecodedSize = GetDecodedSizeOfBuf((UINT8*)Source);

    *DestinationSize = (UINT32)DecodedSize;
    return ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the length of the source file to the compressed file.
You can read the length of the source file through the compressed file when decompressing.

Of course, you can use this for compression,That's the result of my multiple searches

> dstLen  = LZMA_PROPS_SIZE + srcLen + srcLen/3 + 128